# Google App Script - Add Message Pop-Up and Trigger Email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a sheet for my team where they can input requests (the reason I'm not using forms is because this sheet also acts as a sort of calendar that we can all view).

The idea is that when a cell within a column called 'Status' is set to 'Request', this triggers an on-screen message like "Request received" and also triggers an email to me that includes certain information from cells within other columns.

I've got the on-screen message working, but struggling to get an email trigger working *as well*. I can do one or the other, but I can't figure out how to have both message and email triggered (I'm brand new to this). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sheet example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GjK2Z7KKz6CgVe0i51Ub2r1_RqUcPrPFRwCXQP1-Up8/edit?usp=sharing

Email to include: Column A (Brand), Column E (Priority), and Column F (W/C)

Script:

```
function triggerOnEdit(e)
{
showMessageOnApproval(e);
}
function showMessageOnApproval(e)
{
var edited_row = checkStatusIsApproved(e);
if(edited_row > 0)
{
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Row # "+edited_row+" Request received!");
}
}

function checkStatusIsApproved(e)
{
var range = e.range;
if(range.getColumn() <= 7 && 
range.getLastColumn() >=7 )
{
var edited_row = range.getRow();

var status = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(edited row,7).getValue();
if(status == 'Request')
{
return edited_row;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function triggerOnEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Spotlight" && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "Request") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Row # " + e.range.rowStart + " Request received!");
    //Send email
  }
}
```